# Doctrine unsigned validation error storing created_at

Tags: php, validation, doctrine

I'm having problems with the Timestampable functionality in Doctrine 1.2.2 and 1.2.3.

The error I get on trying to save() my Record is:

> Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Validator_Exception' with message 'Validation failed in class XXX 1 field had validation error: * 1 **validator failed on created_at (unsigned)** ' in ...

I've created the relevant field in the MySQL table as:

> `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,

Then in setTableDefinition() I have:

> ```
>     $this->hasColumn('created_at', 'timestamp', null, array(
>          'type' => 'timestamp',
>          'fixed' => false,
>          'unsigned' => false,
>          'primary' => false,
>          'notnull' => true,
>          'autoincrement' => false,
>          ));
> ```

Which is taken straight from the output of generateModelsFromDb().

And finally my setUp() looks like:

> ```
> public function setUp()
> {
>     parent::setUp();
>     $this->actAs('Timestampable', array(
>                                     'created' => array(
>                                                     'name' => 'created_at',
>                                                     'type' => 'timestamp',
>                                                     'format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
>                                                     'disabled' => false,
>                                                     'options' =>  array()
>                                   ),
>                                     'updated' => array(
>                                                     'disabled' => true
>                                   )));
> }
> ```

(I've tried not defining all of those fields for 'created', but I get the same problem.)

I'm a bit stumped as to what I'm doing wrong - for one thing I can't see why Doctrine would be running any unsigned checks against a 'timestamp' datatype...

**Updated**

I'm on Debian Lenny (5.0.8) with MySQL (5.0.51a-24+lenny5O). The problem is occurring with Doctrine 1.2.3 and 1.2.2. I noticed that Doctrine's examples use TIMESTAMP MySQL columns rather than DATETIMEs, so I changed that and re-generated, but the problem still recurred. I also thought it might be a problem with the MySQL definition, so I ran generateSqlFromModels to get the right SQL, but that was fine too (DATETIME NOT NULL).

I'm totally stumped - have logged a bug in Doctrine JIRA to see if I can get this figured out: [DC-965](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-965)

Any help gratefully received!

Alex

Comment: Just a quick update on this: to try an alternative track, I deleted the hasColumn() definition, simplified the actAs to just $this->actAs('Timestampable'), deleted the table in the database and then ran Doctrine::createTablesFromModels().

The error I then got was: "2 fields had validation errors: * 1 validator failed on created_at (unsigned) * 1 validator failed on updated_at (unsigned)"

So I'm pretty sure the error isn't anything to do with the column definitions, either in Doctrine or in MySQL. So what does that leave?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Any update on this guys? I've tried again with all-new code and a fresh install of Doctrine 1.2.3, and the problem is still occurring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesss solved on my case!
And hopefully on your case as well!

When I started the project I worked on, I wanted by default all my columns to be:

```
notnull: true
unsigned: true
```

which you can set in yml config files in symfony or with plain php like:
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_DEFAULT_COLUMN_OPTIONS, array('notnull' => true, 'unsigned' => true));

And of course unsigned attribute DOES NOT get applied in the database for string columns right?
Which made me assume Doctrine wouldn't care either about it... WRONG

When you activate Validators: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/component-overview/pl#validator, Doctrine tries to validate that string column, or timestamp/datime column with an unsigned validator!

On my case removing that default column attribute solved it. And if you haven't set defaults then maybe you should set unsigned as False using that method and then do it per column in your model definition where you need it.

Comment: Many thanks Aservedio for taking the time to post this. I agree - the problem is that Doctrine seems to pass timestamps to the unsigned validator, which is a bit crazy. But the Doctrine team don't seem to want to fix that. Anyway thanks again for the workaround suggestion - I'll let you know how I get on!

Answer (score 0):

Umm... not totally sure about the Doctrine specifics of this, but as you point out, `DATETIME/TIMESTAMP` doesn't deal with the attribute UNSIGNED, as it's not a numeric type.

I would start by removing the `UNSIGNED` declaration from your table definition.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've tried removing the UNSIGNED declaration, and then the UNSIGNED and FIXED, from the table definition but no luck.

Comment: Hmm... something else I spotted: why's there a NULL length declared in the $this->hasColumn([name], [type], [length], [options])? Just an idea but maybe try removing the NULL, or possibly declaring a correct length for a DATETIME field (8?).

Comment: Null is the length you should use for dates and datetimes in Doctrine apparently. I've tried 19 but no change.

Also I tried simplifying the Timestampable to $this->actAs('Timestampable') - then I got "2 fields had validation errors: * 1 validator failed on created_at (unsigned) * 1 validator failed on updated_at (unsigned)". (The table didn't have an updated_at field). Maybe this suggests that it's not a specific issue with an unsigned check, but rather with Doctrine not finding the columns?

Answer (score 0):

You're definition should follow this:
(this from Yaml)

```
created_atn:
  type: timestamp(25)
  fixed: false
  unsigned: false
  primary: false
  notnull: false
  autoincrement: false
```

Comment: Thanks - I've tried your values but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. Very puzzling! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following code into the Base directory and respective file.
And my issue gor solved.. thx

```
  public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->actAs('Timestampable', array(
                                        'created' => array(
                                      'name' => 'created_at',
                                      'type' => 'timestamp',
                                      'format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
                                      'disabled' => false,
                                      'options' =>  array()
                                      ),
                                        'updated' => array(
                                                        'disabled' => true
                                      )));
    }
```